# UPDATE issue with .Include() EF Coe

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I've been following  [ms docs tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/concurrency?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#update-the-edit-page-model) on handling concurrency conflicts in EF core. I have two models:

**Movie.cs**

```
public class Movie
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Release Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    [Range(1, 300)]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(5)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9""'\s-]*$")]
    public string Rating { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] ConcurrencyToken { get; set; }

    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    public Genre Genre { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Title;
    }
}
```

**Genre.cs**

```
public class Genre
{
    public Genre()
    {
        Movies = new List<Movie>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 5)]
    [Display(Name = "Genre Title")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z]*$")]
    public string GenreTitle { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] ConcurrencyToken { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Number of movies")]
    public ICollection<Movie> Movies { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return GenreTitle;
    }
}
```

When I tried to update my **Models** I faced some weird issues and could not figure why, there were no errors thrown, models were just simply not getting updated. Here is my `post` method for **Update**:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int? id)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        // ConcurrencyToken may have changed.
        var movieToUpdate = await _context.Movie
            .Include(m => m.Genre)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);

        if(movieToUpdate == null)
        {
            return HandleDeletedMovie();
        }

        // Set ConcurrencyToken to value read in OnGetAsync
        _context.Entry(movieToUpdate).Property(
            m => m.ConcurrencyToken).OriginalValue = Movie.ConcurrencyToken;

        if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<Movie>(
            movieToUpdate,
            "movie",
            m => m.Title, m => m.ReleaseDate,
            m => m.Price, m => m.Rating,
            m => m.GenreId))
        {
            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToPage("./Index");
            }
            catch(DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {
                var exceptionEntry = ex.Entries.Single();
                var clientValues = (Movie)exceptionEntry.Entity;
                var databaseEntry = exceptionEntry.GetDatabaseValues();

                if(databaseEntry == null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Unable to save. The movie was deleted by another user.");

                    return Page();
                }

                var dbValues = (Movie)databaseEntry.ToObject();
                await SetDbErrorMessage(dbValues, clientValues, _context);

                // Save the current ConcurrencyToken so next postback
                // matches unless an new concurrency issue happens.
                Movie.ConcurrencyToken = (byte[])dbValues.ConcurrencyToken;
                // Clear model error for the next postback
                ModelState.Remove($"{nameof(Movie)}.{nameof(Movie.ConcurrencyToken)}");
            }
        }

        // Get errors from TryUpdate
        var validationErrors = ModelState.Values.Where(E => E.Errors.Count > 0)
        .SelectMany(E => E.Errors)
        .Select(E => E.ErrorMessage)
        .ToList();

        PopelateGenresDropDownList(_context, movieToUpdate.Genre);
        return Page();
    }
```

The update was failing on the line `TryUpdateModelAsync`, and it did not go to `try-catch`. I figured out the error that was causing the issue was validation for the `Genre.GenreTitle` property which is *Include*d in `movie`. Even though **ModelState** was not failing it still caused an error for updating the entity. However, when I checked the **Movie.Genre** property was totally fine and there should not have been any errors. Only when I removed **.Include** from `var movieToUpdate = await _context.Movie.FirstOrDefaultAsync(id)` it worked out.

Now, I'm wondering what was my mistake because in the documentation the nested object was actually *.Include*d.

[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I tested your regular expression `^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z]*$` and it does not seems to accept space caracter. So `Genre Title` is not a match to the expression and trigger an error.

You can add space in the `[]` to tell the expression that you also need to accept space character. I don't know if it is how it's supposed to be done but it works in [RegexStorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester) or [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) (No c# for this last one but Regex are kinda universal I think).

Comment: But when I tried to update my Genre entity and it allowed the spaces for `Genre.Title` itself. Even for the **Titles** with a single word it threw an error... So I think could be something else. But, however, I will try to remove my `regex` and try again, thanks!

Comment: And by the way, when you specify the fields inside of `TryUpdateModelAsync` method, shouldn't EF omit the fields that are not specified there? Because `Genre` is nested inside of `Movie` and EF should not even bother with him as there are no changes made on it, and it is not mentioned in columns list inside of `TryUpdate`.

Comment: @Miraziz Never used TruUpdateModelAsync(), but I don't think it can totally avoid the properties not specified. Since we are talking about models, there might be a instanciation somewhere, and so properties are read, including its attributes. Not sure about it but this is how I see things here, maybe someone will correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Well, then there would be no sense of specifying the properties manually alongside passing the new object. As far as I know, this solution is used for avoiding the **overposting** issue.